# Real-valued Fourier series representation

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series

I have got stuck on the following task:

> Find the value of the series $${4\over \pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty {1\over
>  k^2}-{1\over \pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty{(-1)^k\over k^2}$$ using real-valued Fourier
>   series representation of the $4$-periodic function $$f(x)=(1-|x|)\mathbb{1}_{[-1,1]}(x), \qquad -2<x\leq2$$
>
> where $\mathbb{1}$ is a characteristic function.

I wonder if my real Fourier series is correct, as with what I got I don't know how I can determine the value of the given series.

Here's how I proceed:

At first I would rewrite the function so it looks nicer: $$x\mapsto
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1-|x| & -1\leq x \leq 1\\ 
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{array} 
\right.
$$
As we can easily see the function is even, so the $b_k$ coefficients of the series will be equal $0$. Finding $a_k$:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
a_k&=\int_0^2f(x)\cos {\pi kx \over 2}dx=\int_0^1(1-x)\cos {\pi kx \over 2}dx\\
&\left.=(1-x){2 \over\pi k}\sin{\pi kx \over 2}\right|_0^1+\int_0^1{2 \over\pi k}\sin{\pi kx \over 2}dx\\
&=\left.-{4\over\pi^2k^2}\cos{\pi kx \over 2}\right|_0^1={4\over\pi^2k^2}\left(1-\cos{\pi k \over 2}
\right)\end{eqnarray}$$

So for $k\in \mathbb{Z}^{\ge1}$ we have 3 different cases:
$$
a_k=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
{4\over\pi^2n^2}, & n=2k-1\\ 
{8\over\pi^2n^2}, & n=4k-2\\
0, & n=4k
\end{array} 
\right.
$$
We still need to find $a_0$:
$$a_0=\int_0^11-x\;dx=\left.-\frac12 (1-x)^2\right|_0^1=\frac12$$
So now we can really write the series representation:
$$f(x)\rightsquigarrow \frac12+\sum_{k=1}^\infty {4\over\pi^2(2k-1)^2}\cos\left({\pi(2k-1) \over 2}x\right)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty {8\over\pi^2(4k-2)^2}\cos\left({\pi(4k-2) \over 2}x\right)$$

Is my solution till now correct or not? If yes, how can I tackle the series in the task?

Comment: So far, it's correct (or at least our mistakes are equivalent). You know that the Fourier series of sufficiently nice functions converge pointwise, I suppose. So what do you get if you evaluate the Fourier series for some suitably chosen $x$?

Comment: @DanielFischer That's the point, sure I know that, but I can't figure out at which point I should evaluate function at. Say at $x_0=0$. Then we would get
$$\frac12 + {4\over \pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty {1 \over (2k-1)^2}+{8 \over \pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty {1 \over (4k-2)^2}$$
which in no way as I can see corresponds the demanded series.

Ok let's try $x_0=2$. We get
$$\frac12 - {4\over \pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty {1 \over (2k-1)^2}+{8 \over \pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty {1 \over (4k-2)^2}$$

As well I don't see how we can convert it to the representation in the task.

Comment: Another natural candidate would be $x = 1$. It might be necessary to massage the series a little to get the series in the task. Maybe you even need to combine the evaluations of the Fourier series in different points. Play around a bit. You should be able to find something. Perhaps useful are identities along the lines of $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k-1)^2} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\right).$$

Comment: @DanielFischer ok, I will try, at least I am more sure now that the Fourier is correct, thanks!